# Change default hash function for block hashing

Tags: hash, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

i'm very new with HF and i'm supposed to study this platform for a university project. The first thing assigned is to understand Fabric sources, in particular find where the block creation is done and in which way may be possible to change the default hash function used for blocks creation.

I'v found some files in which may be the interested part, but i'm new with the platform and i really don't know where to get such information.

I've found this:

1. https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.2/common/ledger/blockledger/util.go
   **CreateNewBlock** function
2. https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.2/protos/common/block.go

Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

It IS POSSIBLE to do so, it can be done by replacing hashing function in

```
protos/common/block.go
```

file, as i said in my post ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to the document, currently SHA256 is the only one valid algorithm. And it was hardcoded some places.

However, you can do some experiments, bellow are some configuration places you may want to investigate - 
The BCCSP configuration for both [peer](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.2/sampleconfig/core.yaml) and [orderer](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.2/sampleconfig/orderer.yaml) nodes, and the [channel configuration Hashing Algorithm part](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/config_update.html).

## BCCSP configures the blockchain crypto service providers.

```
BCCSP:
    # Default specifies the preferred blockchain crypto service provider
    # to use. If the preferred provider is not available, the software
    # based provider ("SW") will be used.
    # Valid providers are:
    #  - SW: a software based crypto provider
    #  - PKCS11: a CA hardware security module crypto provider.
    Default: SW

    # SW configures the software based blockchain crypto provider.
    SW:
        # TODO: The default Hash and Security level needs refactoring to be
        # fully configurable. Changing these defaults requires coordination
        # SHA2 is hardcoded in several places, not only BCCSP
        Hash: SHA2
        Security: 256
        # Location of key store. If this is unset, a location will be
        # chosen using: 'LocalMSPDir'/keystore
        FileKeyStore:
            KeyStore:
```

Comment: So, looking at this configuration file, it says
`The default Hash and Security level needs refactoring to be fully configurable. Changing these defaults requires coordination.
SHA2 is hardcoded in several places, not only BCCSP`
which means that actually the platform has hashing functions and procedures hardcoded and may be difficult to make this kind of change, am I right?

Comment: I think so. At least there are more than one places to config. Not sure where it is hardcoded. That's why I mentioned you may want to do some experiments and investigation.